# TensorFlow can't convert from float32 to float32_ref while restoring frozen_graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've having this issue where I want to import a TensorFlow graph I've previously frozen.

**The error :**

```
graph_def is invalid at node 'block1/conv2d/kernel/Assign': Input tensor 'block1/conv2d/kernel:0' Cannot convert a tensor of type float32 to an input of type float32_ref.
```

I've built a custom model mainly for proof of concept purpose within my application. I'm using the tf.layers wrappers for the conv2d and batch_norm.

**The custom model code :**

```
...

@staticmethod
def conv_batch_relu(inputs, filters, kernel_size, is_training):
    cv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=inputs, filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, use_bias=True, activation=None)
    bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs=cv, training=is_training, fused=True)
    return tf.nn.relu(bn)

def build_network(self):

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + self.dataset['input_dims'], name='input')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + [self.dataset['output_dims']], name='labels')
    is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='is_training')

    with tf.variable_scope('block1'):
        conv1 = CNN.conv_batch_relu(inputs=self.x, filters=64, kernel_size=3, is_training=self.is_training)
        conv2 = CNN.conv_batch_relu(inputs=conv1, filters=64, kernel_size=3, is_training=self.is_training)
        pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=2, strides=2)

    with tf.variable_scope('block2'):
        conv3 = CNN.conv_batch_relu(inputs=pool1, filters=128, kernel_size=3, is_training=self.is_training)
        conv4 = CNN.conv_batch_relu(inputs=conv3, filters=128, kernel_size=3, is_training=self.is_training)
        pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv4, pool_size=2, strides=2)

    next_shape = int(pool2.shape[1] * pool2.shape[2] * pool2.shape[3])
    next_output = (next_shape // 4)  

    with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
        flat_fc1 = tf.layers.flatten(inputs=pool2)
        fc1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flat_fc1, units=next_output, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
        fc1_drop = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=fc1)

    with tf.name_scope('logits'):
        self.yhat = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc1_drop, units=self.dataset['output_dims'], activation=None, name='yhat')

    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        self.cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.y, logits=self.yhat), name='cross_entropy')

    self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.hyperparams['learning_rate']['user'], name='optimizer').minimize(self.cross_entropy)
```

An external function is responsible for freezing the graph for inference. I found a blog post (https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc) and followed it for freezing the graph.

**The code responsible for freezing the graph :**

```
absolute_model_dir = '{0}/frozen_model.pb'.format('.')

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
    saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

    node_names = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]

    output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), node_names)

    with tf.gfile.GFile(absolute_model_dir, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Another function is responsible for loading the frozen graph for inference.

**The code responsible for loading the graph :**

```
with tf.gfile.GFile('{0}/frozen_model.pb'.format(path), 'rb') as infile:

    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(infile.read())

    # fix nodes for batch_norm
    # based on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3628
    for node in graph_def.node:
        if node.op == 'RefSwitch':
            node.op = 'Switch'
            for index in range(len(node.input)):
                if 'moving_' in node.input[index]:
                    node.input[index] = node.input[index] + '/read'
        elif node.op == 'AssignSub':
            node.op = 'Sub'
            if 'use_locking' in node.attr: del node.attr['use_locking']
        elif node.op == 'Assign':
            if 'use_locking' in node.attr: del node.attr['use_locking']

    graph = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def) # <---- This is the line that breaks !
```

My TensorFlow version is 1.7 (tensorflow-gpu 1.7) and I've tried 1.6 before, resulting in the same error. I'm currently using Python 3.6.3 in a virtualenv.

Looking at the discussion of the github issue (link in one of the comments above) I'm aware that the '*Assign*' keyword in '*block1/conv2d/kernel/Assign*' seems like a good candidate for the source of the error, but I'm really unsure about how's it being used within tensorflow and why it's causing errors. This all feels a little too much 'black-magic'-ish for me right now.

Did any of you stumbled upon something similar and found an explanation about what is going wrong ?

Any help appreciated, thanks !